# How to reset selected rows in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightningtreegrid

I try to reset the selected rows on an LWC within a lightning-grid.
I'm starting an LWC inside of an Aura Wrapper because I have to use the URL-Addressable interface. This works fine and the component gets loaded.

Problem: When I select some rows in the grid and click on the 'Cancel' button which navigates me back to e.g. my Account record and then I start again the component the rows are still selected.
In the past, I have done some similar stuff but with an Aura-Grid and not the LWC grid and there it was possible for me to reset the selected values like:

```
cmp.find('treegrid_async').set('v.selectedRows', []);
```

When I try the following inside the `handlecancelclick` function its not working:

```
let tree = this.template.querySelector('my-hierarchy-grid');
or
let tree = this.template.querySelector('lightning-tree-grid');
```

I have also tried already to put all this stuff into the `connectedCallback` and/or `disconnectedCallback` function but nothing work.
Hopefully some of you have an idea.

Here is my code:
First Component

```
<template>
    <my-hierarchy-grid onrowsselected={handlerowselection}>
    </my-hierarchy-grid>
    <div>
        <lightning-button label="Cancel" title="Cancel" onclick={handlecancelclick}>
        </lightning-button>
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save" title="Save"
            onclick={handlesaveclick} disabled={isSaveButtonDisabled}>
        </lightning-button>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS Part

```
handlerowselection(event) {
    this.isSaveButtonDisabled = event.detail.isSelected;
    this.selectedItems = event.detail.selectedItems;
}   

handlecancelclick(event) {
    // Here I would like to remove all selected items
    console.log('click');               < works
    console.log(this.selectedItems);    < works
    this.selectedItems = [];            < works
    console.log(this.selectedItems);    < is empty but the still checked in the view
    /*
    let pageRef = {
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: 'CustomObject__c',
            actionName: 'view',
            recordId: this.recordId
        }
    };
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](pageRef, true);
    */
}
```

Snd Component

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-var-m-top_medium slds-var-m-bottom_x-large">
        <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-var-m-bottom_medium">
            Some Text
        </h2>
        <div class="slds-var-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
            <lightning-tree-grid class="lgc-example-treegrid" columns={gridColumns} data={gridData}
                expanded-rows={gridExpandedRows} key-field="Id" is-loading={gridLoadingState}
                ontoggle={handleRowToggle} onrowselection={setSelectedRows} selected-rows={selectedItems}>
                >
            </lightning-tree-grid>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS part

```
@api selectedItems
setSelectedRows() {
    let treeGrid = this.template.querySelector('lightning-tree-grid');
    let selItems = [];
    treeGrid.getSelectedRows().forEach(function (item) {
        selItems.push(item.somevalue);

    });

    if (Array.isArray(selItems) && selItems.length) {
        let e = {
            isSelected: false,
            selectedItems: selItems
        }
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('rowsselected', {
            detail: e,
        }));
    } else {
        let e = {
            isSelected: true,
            selectedItems: selItems
        }
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('rowsselected', {
            detail: e
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just reset `this.selectedRows = []`, it will deselect all the rows.

Comment: Its not working. At least when I put it into the `handlecancelclick` function. I have also tried `this.selectedItems = []`but this also do not work

Comment: change `selected-rows={selectedRows}` to `selected-rows={selectedItems}` in  the html markup and make sure that you have defined `selectedItems ` as a property in js controller class.

Comment: I have updated the code above but it' still not working. I really do not understand it